# Как добавить в массив наследуемого класса

Tags: php

Дано задание "Даны два класса. Класс В является наследником класса А. Требуется чтобы в классе В метод getDate возвращал данные родительского метода, дополненные элементом массива с индексом sum с любым значением." Помогите пожалуйста, я новичок в этой сфере.

```
class A
{
    Public function getDate()
    {
        Return array('count' => '1');
    }
}

class B extends A
{
    public function merge()
    {
       $b = array ('summ' => '5');
        return array_push( $this->getDate(),$b);
    }
}

$new = new B();
print_r( $new->merge())
```

Answer (score -1):

```
class A
{
    Public function getDate()
    {

        return array('count' => '1');
    }
}

class B extends A
{
    public function merge()
    {

       $arr=array ();
       $arr=$this->getDate();
       $arr[summ]=5;

       return  $arr;
    }
}

$new = new B();
print_r( $new->merge());
```

Comment: Минус мне за что? Решение рабочее ведь :(

Comment: Минус не мой, но судя по описанию "Требуется чтобы в классе В метод getDate" - я так понимаю надо переопределить `getDate` в потомке.

Comment: а чем public  не гож ?

Comment: Надо вызывать `getDate` а не `merge`. При чем тут `public`.

Comment: Да тут вызов merge  для дебага. Просто глянуть что в нем. Этот вызов не будет таковым как я полагаю

Comment: Это явная задача на переопределение метода в классе-потомке, в вашем ответе этого не видно.

Comment: можно и так предположить. Возможно переопределение. Хотя я не понимаю смысла переопределять в данной задаче которую указал автор